# Leak in kitchen sink hose

Tags: sealing, kitchen-sink, hose

[image]I have a leak in my kitchen sink hose. I first tried to detach the hose myself but it was very difficult. A plumber came out said that possibly due to a new countertop and how tight our space is under the sink (i just moved in in March so I don't know if the countertop is original or not) detaching the hose would risk severe damage to pipes underneath the sink. The sink hose can't be detached with a wrench, he needed some special tool to attempt to detach it.

He said the best option is to get a new faucet ($425 installation in Chicago) and then he can cut the current faucet and install the new one without going through this aforementioned process that could cause a lot of damage. Does this sound right?

I was also thinking about applying some Flex Seal to the hose but I'm worried about its toxicity. If we use the sink water for cooking and the water is contacting the dried Flex Seal is this a health hazard?

Its the black hose with the white plastic piece on the connector

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the faucet itself then replace the hose and reinstall both. While at it see if you could enlarge the access area. I believe that special tool is available at your favorite box store, I purchased one many years ago and it was not that expensive. Before removing the faucet check if you will need farels or other parts first so it can be a  one shot repair. Good luck and a dry future:-)

Comment: Get a plumber, not some guy trying to take your money.

Comment: Please post photos of the faucet from above and from below, and of the various water and drain pipes under the sink.  It's otherwise hard to know if there are older supply pipes without standard shutoffs, and where all the piping/tubing is routed.

Comment: I'm not sure of the composition of FlexSeal, but there are a number of silicone "repair tapes" available that I would have no concern about contamination. They tend to be on the expensive side, probably a dollar a foot or more. If you are happy with your faucet otherwise, that's what I would try first. Replacing a faucet (keeping old sink and drain) is a bit involved, but well within most people's ability if you can take it steady and slow and make sure you have the specific tools handy.

Comment: Thank you, i just updated it with some pictures. That repair tape sounds like a good thing to try, would you be able to recommend a specific brand/product name?

Comment: Those repairs tapes are mainly for temporary use.  Trusting them for years and expect to go away for a week or two is asking for problems.

Comment: Forget about flex seal -- it's junk. Anyway, the faucet went in once, so it'll come out. The first plumber just wasn't very good at his job.

Answer (score 4):

If the leak is in the black spray head hose and not the connector you may be able to acquire a replacement from the manufacturer. If the hose has a hex end at the sprayer and it's threaded on replace just the hose if not it may be crimped and the whole head needs replaced.

That hose appears to be a simple quick connect assembly hose and should be very simple to remove. It attaches by simply pushing together, I believe to release it you push the white plastic collar upward towards the larger brass barrel and simultaneously pull down on the end of the hose fitting. The small diameter brass cylinder pulls out from the plastic sleeve and large brass barrel. It may require a firm push and pull.

If the whole faucet needs replacement there's nothing to complicate it here. That is all typical and in good uncorroded condition. A competent plumber will take a basin wrench or faucet installation tool to unscrew the supply hoses behind the sink and something like a 5/8" deep socket tool to loosen the faucet mount nut then it comes out.